# Display Custom Taxonomy of custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, loop, page-template

I am stuck on trying to create a template page that displays a list of the names in a specific custom taxonomy of a custom post type I created.

The custom taxonomy is `locations` and clicking on a location like *New York*, should take you to a list of all the post types that are connected to that location.

I have looked at `get_the_terms_list` but I have not been able to produce the list.
Don't really know what steps and pages I have to create to do all this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: code samples would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

I am assiming you already register taxonomy which show you correct links (and generate correct rewrite rules)... but lets make a checklist.

### 1) Register Taxonomy and assign it to different post types

done by you...

### 2) Modify a rewrite rules

```
add_filter('locations_rewrite_rules', 'se_119400_locations_rewrite_rules');
function se_119400_locations_rewrite_rules(){
    $rules = array();
    $rules['location(/?(([^/]+?)(/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?)?)?)$']     = 'index.php?locations=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[5]&post_type=any';
    return $rules;
}
```

### 3) Taxonomy template?

Create a taxonomy template `taxonomy-locations.php` - this will show you a list of posts..

### 4) Actuall locations list/cloud?

[wp_tag_cloud](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud)

```
<?php
 wp_tag_cloud(array('taxonomy' => 'locations'));
```

Comment: The code can be affected by my framework functionality (i did a tests on dev enviropment with taxonomy location - which is almost same), but in general it working example.

Comment: Which page would the code for the rewrite rules go?

Comment: And what page would the code for the list/cloud go?

Comment: rewrite rules to `functions.php` and the wp_tag_cloud to place where you want to show the locations tags cloud

Comment: Awesome! This worked for me.

Comment: How do you go about adding the same font size for each tag no matter which one is used more?

Comment: if you don't like the output of the wp_tag_cloud you can output a list using `wp_list_categories` or even do yourself a output code requesting all terms of your taxonomy and showing it in front end...